# Discord bot using discord.js not playing mp3 file, no errors given

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

My code reaches line 24 `const dispatcher = connection.play('/sounds/Pigstep.mp3', { volume: 0.9 });`, I know that because the `console.log('audio is now playing!')` on line 26 gets executed. The bot does come into the voice channel but it doesn't play the song. I get no error messages in the terminal.

My bot has permissions to join a voice channel and speak.
I have ffmpeg installed and added to path.

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const auth = require('./auth.json');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login(auth.token);

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', async msg => {
    if (msg.content.substring(0, 1) === '!') {
        console.log('Message received!');
        let args = msg.content.substring(1).split(' ');
        const cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch (cmd) {
            case 'cricket':
                var connection = await msg.member.voice.channel.join();
                const dispatcher = connection.play('/sounds/Pigstep.mp3', { volume: 0.9 });
                dispatcher.on('start', () => {
                    console.log('audio is now playing!');
                });
                console.log('Playing!');
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: What line is line 22?

Comment: is this `console.log('audio is now playing!');` line 26?

Comment: yes it is, I'll add that to the question as well

Comment: Do you have FFMPEG installed?

Comment: @EvanSmith yes i have it installed and added to my path, before I got the error that it could not find ffmpeg but that was resolved by installing it.

Answer (score 0):

Play requires absolute path. Also make sure you have the right directory in your code for the file

```js
connection.play(require("path").join(__dirname, '/sounds/Pigstep.mp3'));
```